# Find the number of retweets of a retweet using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

If I retweet a tweet, is there a way of finding out how many times "my retweet" has been retweeted / favorited? Are there provisions in the Twitter API to retrieve that? There is no key in `retweeted_status` which gives that information. What am I missing here?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can track it. Get the stats(favorite, retweet_count) of your retweet(time when you are retweeting it.) and save this stats somewhere as a check-point. Next time when someone is going to retweet it again you will get an updated stats of the your previous retweet and do compare latest stats with the existing check-point.

Comment: Not quite, future retweets can be other child retweets.

Comment: @sanjay-yadav What you say is fine if the original tweet is mine and if I wanted to know number of retweets gained per hour / day etc. But this is entirely different from the question asked.

Comment: @richie did you find any way to obtain count of retweets in a time period?

Comment: @scopeInfinity haven't been able to identify a solution yet

Comment: @richie have you found a solution?

Comment: @Naeem Nope. No luck.